# Unable to find any WiFi Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04, network-manager

I am using the wireless adapter rtl8188ee on ubuntu 22.04 trying to connect from GUI doesn't work, and attempting to manually connect from nmcli in the terminal gives me the output Error: No network with SSID 'xxxxx' found. dmesg doesn't show anything strange.

Any help would be appreciated -

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator What do I do with the post you linked, doesn't make any sense